# Can registerUserNotificationSettings be called in xcode 5 for ios 8 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As iOS 8 deprecates registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and uses registerUserNotificationSettings, when I run code for iOS 8 device using Xcode 5 registerUserNotificationSettings not getting called.

I am using this code:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
         #else

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
           #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the iOS 8 SDK comes with Xcode 6. If you're trying to run it from Xcode 5 I'm assuming it's still using the iOS 7 SDK so this method won't exist yet. There are ways of using the iOS 8 SDK with Xcode 5, but personally I would just upgrade to Xcode 6 as it's designed to be used with the iOS 8 SDK which is the biggest change to the SDK since its release.

So upgrade to Xcode 6, build it again, and it should work as expected.